# How to store Mysql as time?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a nudge feature on my website to allow users to nudge each other, how i what to have a 5-minute cooldown on this so users can't spam this feature. My current idea for how to store this is to create a last nudged column which stores the time of nudgeing after the first nudge then.

So basically the question is how do I store mysql as time in this way?

Comment: Just store the nudge, and then for each incoming nudge use `DATEDIFF()` to check how much time has elapsed.

Comment: But you should also be prepared for denial of service attacks, which could  be engineered by bots trying to nudge your app to death.

Answer (score 0):

Create a column with name like `last_activity' or 'last_nudge` with `datetime` datatype. In datatime column you can hold datetime value like:

`2017-04-20 08:30:00` i.e. `Y-m-d H:i:s`

On each new entry check the date time difference and do your task.

Comment: ah that makes a lot of sense, would you mind giving me an example of the code you would use for checking the date time difference, thanks friend.

Comment: Check this: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/12168e2cdd3b12cd7b6ba6db240f00d817e3b8cb

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and accept the answer if it helps you. And still you need some help then ping me on skype

Comment: sadly i cant yet because i dont have 15 rep